# NSPopUpButton is NOT displaying my last saved selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am having trouble figuring out how to properly use the `NSPopUpButton` class with pop-up menus.

I have the basic working.  I can display, select and save my selection from the pop-up window in my `NSPopUpButton versionsPopupOutlet` object (which is part of my PreferenceController object).

The PreferenceController object is my Preferences window for the program.

I can close and open up again the Preferences window and it shows my last selection!  Great!

But when I quit and run my program again, the `NSPopUpButton versionsPopupOutlet` object does NOT show my last saved selection (which the program will ultimately use).  It always shows the first item in the pop-up menu of the `NSPopUpButton versionsPopupOutlet` object (which may or may not be correct).

The code is simple.

`PreferenceController.h` is:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>


@interface PreferenceController : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *versionsPopupOutlet;
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender;
@end
```

`PreferenceController.m` is:

```
#import "PreferenceController.h"


@implementation PreferenceController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
    NSString *commonlist = @"/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin";  // Added /opt/local/bin
    NSString *pathlist = [environment objectForKey:@"PATH"];
    NSArray *commonItems = [commonlist componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSArray *pathItems = [pathlist componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *path;
    BOOL duplicate;
    unsigned int i, h;

    for (i = 0; i < [commonItems count]; i++)
    {
        path = [[commonItems objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:@"/lame"];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
            [versionsPopupOutlet addItemWithTitle:path];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < [pathItems count]; i++)
    {
        duplicate = FALSE;
        for (h = 0; h < [commonItems count]; h++)
        {
            if ([[pathItems objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[commonItems objectAtIndex:h]])
                duplicate = TRUE;
        }
        if (!duplicate)
        {
            path = [[pathItems objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:@"/lame"];
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
                [versionsPopupOutlet addItemWithTitle:path];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    if ([versionsPopupOutlet indexOfSelectedItem] == 0)
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"lamePath"];
    else
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[versionsPopupOutlet titleOfSelectedItem] forKey:@"lamePath"];
    [self close];
}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    [[self window] close];
}
@end
```

In my main GUI program, I have:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
     NSMutableDictionary *defaultValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [defaultValues setObject:@"" forKey:@"lamePath"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
}
```

As you can see, the value for the pop-up menu is stored in a preference file via `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:` method in the `(IBAction)save:(id)sender` method shown above. The question is how do I set the pop-up menu to display the last saved item from the pop-up menu from the saved preference file?

I can obtain the last saved value in the preference file using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lamePath"]`. But how does one tell the popup menu to display this last saved value when I run the Preference window is first displayed?

Comment: Are you using a pull-down or pop-up menu?

Comment: I am using a pop-up menu.

Comment: P.S. I have updated my question accordingly making it clear that I am using pop-up menus.

Comment: Is the question how to select an item of a `NSPopUpButton`? Is the value stored in the preferences file?

Comment: Yes, the value for the pop-up menu is stored in a preference file via  `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:` method in the `(IBAction)save:(id)sender` method shown above.  The question is how do I set the pop-up menu to display the last saved item from the pop-up menu from the saved preference file?  I can obtain the last saved value using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lamePath"]`.  But how does one tell the popup menu to display this last saved value.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `NSPopUpButton`. There are several methods to select an item in the "Setting the current selection" section.

Comment: @Willeke.  I think I figure it out.  The NSPopUpButton object is complicated!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  I needed to add the following to the end of the `(void)windowDidLoad()` method in `PreferenceController.m`

```
[versionsPopupOutlet selectItemWithTitle:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lamePath"]];
```

The statement above reads the last saved pop-up menu selection from standardUserDefaults and then selects it in the populated pop-up menu.

So the `(void)windowDidLoad()` method in `PreferenceController.m` now reads:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
    NSString *commonlist = @"/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin";  // Added /opt/local/bin
    NSString *pathlist = [environment objectForKey:@"PATH"];
    NSArray *commonItems = [commonlist componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSArray *pathItems = [pathlist componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *path;
    BOOL duplicate;
    unsigned int i, h;

    for (i = 0; i < [commonItems count]; i++)
    {
        path = [[commonItems objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:@"/lame"];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
            [versionsPopupOutlet addItemWithTitle:path];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < [pathItems count]; i++)
    {
        duplicate = FALSE;
        for (h = 0; h < [commonItems count]; h++)
        {
            if ([[pathItems objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[commonItems objectAtIndex:h]])
                duplicate = TRUE;
        }
        if (!duplicate)
        {
            path = [[pathItems objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:@"/lame"];
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
                [versionsPopupOutlet addItemWithTitle:path];
        }
    }
    [versionsPopupOutlet selectItemWithTitle:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lamePath"]];
}
```